# Проблемы с кодировкой русских символов в json

Tags: javascript, json, кодировка, fetch

При передаче fetch-запроса на сервер в пересылаемых данных присутствуют русские буквы. На сервере они сохраняются с нарушением кодировки, получается что-то типа этого:
`"u0437u0434u0435u0441u044c u0440u0443u0441u0441u043au0438u0439 u0442u0435u043au0441u0442"`

Я видел способы решения, но они все для php, например, поставить в json_encode флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Мне это не подходит, так как запрос уже приходит сломанный. Как сделать это для java script?

Код запроса:

```
let body = {
    method: 'backupSavedGames',
    save: 'здесь русский текст',
};
fetch('/Jumpers/handle.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
})
```

Comment: Проверяли в какой кодировке файл с javascript кодом? Он UTF-8?